# Exporting project settings from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I work with a repository with over seven hundred Eclipse projects in it, with a plethora of dependencies between them. Only a subset of it concerns me (something like fifty) and I already imported most of them. These projects naturally aren't inside a workspace. I.e. they all were created as a new "Java Project" but I unchecked "Use default location" in the "New Java Project" dialog and gave it the path to them.

Now I'm changing my dev machine and would like to export all of them, so I do not have to create all of these projects by hand. Is there a tool that does something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming by repository you are just referring to a collection of projects neatly tucked away in some local directory or on a NAS as opposed to Git, SVN, or other.

**Option #1 - Generic**

Once you have moved your repository, if necessary,

1. Open **File->Import->Existing Projects into Workspace**.
2. Use **Browse...** to navigate and select the root of your repository. Depending on the number of projects contained thereunder, it may take some time to populate the **Projects** list.
3. Using the **Projects** list, select all projects that you wish to include in your new workspace.
4. *Ensure that the **Copy projects into workspace** option is **unchecked**.*
5. Click **Finish** to start the workspace import.

While this still requires some 50-odd clicks to select each of your projects, it should be far less painful than manually creating projects via the **New Java Project** wizard.

**Option #2 - Workspace**

If you copy over your existing Eclipse installation and store your projects in the same location as on the original system, you can try copying your current Workspace folder. I don't recommend this if you are using a new version of Eclipse and/or different plugins.

Comment: Sadly, copying the workspace to another machine (with the same specs and Eclipse version) did not work... But the importing suggestion still saved me a lot of time! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to hear that the workspace copy didn't work. Then again, when moving over to a new machine it is probably a good idea not to carry over all the junk that collects in `.settings` over time.